# Microsoft R, reading multiple files with different dates in their name: Looking for specific date range

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

Question Answered by Greg below:
To avoid whitespace, you should use paste0("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADDED",Monday,".csv") or paste("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADDED",Monday,".csv", sep = ""). You see, trimws() only trims leading and trailing whitespace, but once you omit sep = "" in your paste() statement paste("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADDED",Monday,".csv"), the damage is already done: the whitespace is trapped in the middle, rather than at the ends.

as the title states, I am using microsoft R and I am trying to read multiple files at once.  The issue is there are dates in the file name using this naming convention:

HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADD_2022-01-01
HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADD_2022-01-02
HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADD_2022-01-03
etc..

These files are generated 7 days a week but I am only interested in the files that are generated M-F.  I currently do this by manually updating the dates in each READ but I am wanting to automate this a bit more.

How can I tell R to look back at specific dates?

Current process:
Friday afternoon I combine files from that week M-F (the friday file generates in the morning)
I do a little bit of filtering/manipulation
Save the newly formatted file to be picked up by another department.

I currently read the files as such:

```
Leads1 <- read.csv("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADD2022-01-17.csv",
                   colClasses = 'character')
Leads2 <- read.csv("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADD2022-01-18.csv",
                       colClasses = 'character')

Leads3 <- read.csv("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADD2022-01-19.csv",
                       colClasses = 'character')
```

Is it possible to write the READ commands to include the file header HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADD and then specific dates like today - 4 for Leads1, today - 3 for Leads2 ?

I have figured out how to do this to write a file, but I can't get it working to read a file.

Here is how I write a file using this method:

```
TodayDate <- today()

finished <- paste("my_file_path/AD/",TodayDate,"Leads3ADLeads2021.csv", sep = "")
write.csv(LoadA2, finished, row.names=FALSE, na="")
```

My attempt at using this method to read

```
Monday <- today()-4
Monday2 <- paste("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADDED",Monday,".csv")
leads1 <- read.csv(Monday2, colClasses = 'character')
```

I get an error stating the file cannot be read because the file path does not exist.  The 'paste' for Monday2 adds spaces to the name:

```
cannot open file 'my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADDED 2022-01-17 .csv': No such file or directory
```

I have tried several ways to remove the white space (I assume its a white space) from the Monday2 string.. all of them have failed.

```
> Monday <- today()-4 %>% trimws()
Error in unclass(as.Date(e1)) - e2 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
> Monday <- today()-4 %>% mutate(as.character) %>% trimws()
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
> Monday <- mutate(str_trim(Monday))
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
> Monday2 <- mutate(str_squish(Monday2))
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first option works, if you block it with `()` or `{}` `(today()-4) %>% trimws()
[1] "2022-01-17"`,  `mutate` wouldn't work because the input is not a data.frame/tibble

Comment: To avoid whitespace, you should use `paste0("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADDED",Monday,".csv")` or  `paste("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADDED",Monday,".csv", sep = "")`. You see, `trimws()` only trims *leading* and *trailing* whitespace, but once you omit `sep = ""` in your `paste()` statement `paste("my_file_path/HP_PLAN_TYPE_ADDED",Monday,".csv")`, the damage is already done: the whitespace is trapped in the middle, rather than at the ends.

Comment: @akrun, you were correct.. wrapping in ( ) allowed the code to run, however it did not solve the white spaces in my string.  Good knowledge to have though :)

Comment: @Greg This was exactly what I was looking for!  This removed the whitespace(s) from the string and allowed me to read the file.  

Thank you both!

Comment: I do not see a place to mark an answer 'correct'.. how do I credit you?

Comment: It is because your `paste` `sep` by default is space.  Check `?paste` `paste (..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL, recycle0 = FALSE)`